# Add a Folder to an ImageField

Tags: 7, media

I'm currently trying to setup a picture gallery with Drupal 7. The Gallery module is set up and works, but it needs pictures added to an image field.

Since I have thousands of pictures to add, I don't want to add them one by one. The best solution for me would be uploading them via FTP and then adding the whole folder into the image field.

I found a script (http://drupal.org/node/1266646) which would do this for me, but it's for Drupal 6 and it doesn't work anymore.

I also tried IMCE with FileField Sources, but I can't add files I uploaded via FTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [IMCE for FileField](http://drupal.org/project/imce_filefield) module suits your use case. The description given in its project page is the following.

> IMCE for FileField allows users to select files from IMCE File Browser. It supports FTP uploaded files by automatically registering them as IMCE files thus making them usable in a [FileField](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield).
>
> [image: screenshot]

The latest stable release (7.x-1.1) has been released on April 8, 2015. It's covered by the security advisory policy. The development snapshot for that release has been last update on August 11, 2017.
As of April 10, 2021, there are 5 bug reports still open; two bugs are marked major, and one is marked critical; the older of them has been opened almost 7 years ago. Only one of them got a reply from the project owner, who is also the only project maintainer.

Comment: thanks it works like a charm :). I had to implement 2 patches manually, though. (http://drupal.org/node/1597366#comment-6031346 and http://drupal.org/node/1591410#comment-6031342)